# Request or response filters via annotations for forwarding (enabling client side routing) in Quarkus

Tags: angular, routes, quarkus, vert.x

I am using Quarkus (3.4.3) to both host my backend rest endpoints as well as my Angular SPA which is just a very simple interface to actually interact with those rest endpoints.

My issue is a quite common one actually. I need client side forwarding to work so that I can directly access e.g. https://host:8080/home.

I am aware that since there is no home resource on the server, I need the request to be redirected to index.html (https://host:8080/) while keeping the home part in the URL for the client side forwarding to take place.

As a solution I want to use Request or response filters via annotations  (as described on https://quarkus.io/guides/resteasy-reactive). I have also found another solution using a ContainerResponseFilter (https://marcelkliemannel.com/articles/2022/routes-forwarding-for-javascript-frontends-in-quarkus/).

Unfortunately I cannot use the ContainerResponseFilter solution as the HttpResponse forward part seems to be outdated/incorrect (these methods do not exist on any available HttpResponse class).

I would prefer to use the annotation method anyway, but I just can’t find a way to implement it properly.

When I tried @ServerRequestFilter(preMatching = true) the issue is that I don’t know how I could redirect/forward the user (requestContext.setRequestUri does nothing).

```java
@ServerRequestFilter(preMatching = true)
    public void preMatchingFilter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
        URI newLocation = URI.create("http://host:8080/");
        requestContext.setRequestUri(newLocation);
    }
```

With @ServerResponseFilter, the issue is that the response has already been written at this point.

Could someone please show me a very simple example of how to forward requests from https://host:8080/home to https://host:8080/ while keeping the path /home so that client side routing will take place?

Answer (score 0):

The @ServerResponseFilter can be used to alter the response. For example this will create a response telling the browser to redirect:

```
@ServerResponseFilter
public void forwardingFilter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, 
                             ContainerResponseContext responseContext){

    URI newLocation = URI.create("http://host:8080/");
    responseContext.getHeaders().putSingle("Location", newLocation);
    responseContext.setStatus(Response.Status.TEMPORARY_REDIRECT.getStatusCode());
}
```

I hope this is applicable to your scenario.